# populating a wxGrid from an array using a range for rows

Tags: loops, wxpython

This should be simple but I'm tearing my hair out trying to make it work:

I want to populate a grid with the values from an sqlite query.

```
rowNum = 3  # This is from a 'select count' query

row_num = range(rowNum)  # This gives me [0, 1, 2]

tbl = [('apple', 'fruit'), ('bacon', 'meat'), ('rose', 'flower')]   # from another query

for row in tbl:
    cells = row[0:2]
    for i in range(len(cells)):
    self.mygrid.SetCellValue(row_num, i, str(cells[i]))
```

This tells me 'overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'

```
for a in row_num:
    for row in tbl:
        cells = row[0:2]
        for i in range(len(cells)):
        self.mygrid.SetCellValue(row_num[a], i, str(cells[i]))
```

This populates three rows of the grid with 'rose' in col 1 and 'flower' in col2

I know this is a simple iteration problem but my mind doesn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block you do SetCellValue(row_num... where row_num is always [0, 1, 2].

In the second, you actually have 3 cycles, the innermost always writes all rows from tbl into the same row (row_num[a]), and the last one stays.

How about this:

```
for (row_idx, row) in enumerate(tbl):
    for (col_idx, col) in enumerate(row[0:2]):
        self.mygrid.SetCellValue(row_idx, col_idx, str(col))
```